# Links wont break in Excel 2007. How do I fix?

Tags: excel-2007

I have a workbook created in excel 2007 and links will not break. How can I go about fixing this problem. I have tried using VBA to do this as well.

I have created this workbook form right clicking and copying two sheets to a new workbook. Then I try to break there links. This was working in the past but I have done some edits and now it's no longer working.

In addition, I often get an error such as "found unreadable content in test.xlsx"  after breaking links and then reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the links to the original workbook weren't really broken, and the original workbook is no longer where it was when you created the link.  To verify, searching for the the full path name of the original workbook in your current workbook using CTRL-F with the option "Look in Formulas".

Did you copy the sheets by right-clicking on them or did you move them?

If copied them instead of moving, in the future do this:

1. Open all of the relevant linked books at the same time, in the same session of Excel.
2. Make sure all of the individual worksheets have unique names.
3. Pick one file to be the new combined workbook.
4. Make sure all of the other workbooks have at least one empty worksheet.
5. Right-click on the worksheet tab for each worksheet in the linked files and select Move or Copy option.
6. Set the To Workbook dropdown to the file you chose in (3).
7. Close the linked workbooks *without saving changes* to preserve them.
8. Save the combined file under a different name so that the original file is also preserved.

It's cumbersome, but far better than suffering with linked workbooks, which are Evil.  Best practice is to never EVER create linked workbooks in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Name manager... Look for "refers to".. some other document... Has driven me crazy before... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you can't find the external links go to File -> Check for Issues -> Check Compatibility.
It will show you all possible errors in that workbook and if you scroll down you will find linked cells.